# Weird object referencing in Lazarus

Tags: class, inheritance, lazarus

I'm experincing a very weird and erratical behaviour in Lazarus 0.9.30.2 version FPC 2.4.4. as shown in the code snippet below after calling NormalizeVEctor procedure in objects, e1 and ne1 becomes the same value whereas I was intending to preserve the original value of vector in e1 and ne1 will represent the normalized value of that vector.

```
var 
   e1,e2, ne1, ne2, bisector, speed,res :QVector2D;

begin 
e1 := QVector2D.Create; 
e2 := QVector2D.Create;
ne1 := QVector2D.Create; 
ne2 := QVector2D.Create;
.....
.....
ne1 := e1; 
ne2 := e2;
ne1.NormalizeVector;  ne2.NormalizeVector;// ne1 = e1 are the same values 
bisector := SubtractVector(ne2,ne1);
```

QVector declaration is as shown below

```
   QVector2D = class(TPersistent)
   public
    Vector :TVector3D;
    function length: Single;
    function NormalizeVector:QVEctor2D;
   end;
```

Comment: Objects are pointers, with `ne1 := e1` 'ne1' now refers to the same object that 'e1' refers, and you'll leak what previously 'ne1' referred. See [docs](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/classes/tpersistent.assign.html).

Comment: That issue is still vague for me, every now and then I experience those kind of problem in my programms especially those deriving from ancestors and where object acrhitectures are written by me, probably the whole acrhitecture of me is lame. Anyway If I've used Assign or AssignTO procedures then probably reference to same object thesis should be correct but I never used the Assign instead I've believe that I eliminated that by creating completely new object to get the fresh memory chunk for object ne1;

Comment: Yes, and those chunks(ne1,ne2 original allocations) now are leaked.